# What is happening when I initialize a std::string with 0?

Tags: c++

For instance, lets say I have
    `std::string str = 0;`

Is the 0 being converted to a const char*?
Is it being coverted to a char* and then to a const char* when it's passed to the constructor?

<s>I understand initializing a char* to 0 is undefined behavior, and as far as I know the same goes for const char*, but I don't understand the process of what's going on when I pass 0 to the std::string constructor.</s>
Edit: I was wrong.

Comment: What compiler are you using?  My version of g++ throws a runtime error.... presumably you're passing a pointer (0x0?).

Comment: I'm using g++ and it does indeed throw a runtime error, I'm jut looking for clarification of what's going on behind the scenes.

Comment: Others have answered it with more detail, but you can look at the source:
https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/basic_string.tcc [line 573 or so]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct in your guessing.

If we look at e.g. [this `std::string` constructor reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) we can see that the only suitable constructor is number 5. Therefore your definition is equal to

```
std::string str = std::string(0);
```

And as noted in the reference:

> The behavior is undefined if s does not point at an array of at least `Traits::length(s)+1` elements of CharT, **including the case when s is a null pointer**.

<sub>[Emphasis mine]</sub>

So yes it constructs a `std::string` from the null-pointer which is indeed UB.

Answer (score 1):

> I understand initializing a char* to 0 is undefined behavior

You understand wrong. A 0 literal can be converted to a null pointer constant of any pointer type. There's nothing undefined there. The issues come when there's overloading involved, and the 0 can be converted not just to a pointer, but to another integral type. But that conversion itself is not problematic on its own.

Which brings us to what `std::string str = 0;` does. It initializes `str`, a class type, from 0. So we need to examine [constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string), the only applicable one for 0 is this one:

```
basic_string( const CharT* s,
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

So it indeed initializes `str` from a null pointer. And that is what's undefined.